# Decode Html entity

Tags: html, delphi, encode

My project is in delphi code.

I'm get some rest response from a call.

But in the response we have some encode values.

```
{

    href: https://gemshop1.ccvshop.be/api/rest/v1/Categories/22470262/
    id: 22470262
    name: "ra&auml;r"
    description: "Iet&#39;s m&euml;t r&agrave;&agrave;r"
    position: 4
    show_on_website: true
    deeplink: http://gemshop1.ccvshop.be/raär
    children: [ ]

}
```

Like the property 'name' and 'description' are encode.
How can I decode `ra&auml;r`  into `raär`?

I've use `THTMLEncoding.HTML.Decode` but that did not work.

On [HTML unicode utf-8](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_latin1_supplement.asp) I get a list of entity like `ä` encoded to `&auml;`

Is there a function like `THTMLEncoding.HTML.Decode` that do the job.
Or must I replace with StringReplace

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657105/delphi-html-decode ?

Comment: Yes, but I was looking for something like THTMLEncoding.HTML.Decode

Comment: JSON is not supposed to contain HTML-encoded strings. You should report the issue to the service provider.

Comment: @Olivier Yes, I did it. Sometime they use HTML-encoded strings and for other calls they don't use it. Confused

Comment: On the page given by Andreas, you should focus on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47875172/12763954).

Comment: @Olivier Yes, I'm testing the HtmlDecode from Ian Boyd