# Issue with html decoding in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I have a problem with TNETEncoding.HTML.Decode in Delphi 10.3.3 (rio).

It seems the decoding is not functioning correctly but maybe i'm doing something wrong here.

```
var s := TNETEncoding.HTML.Decode('carri&egrave;re');
```

returns in s:

```
'carri&egrave;re'
```

It should be 'carrière' (without de quotes).  See: https://www.convertstring.com/en/EncodeDecode/HtmlDecode

Is there something i'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the official documentation of [`THTMLEncoding`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.NetEncoding.THTMLEncoding), it only supports character entities for the reserved HTML characters `"`, `&`, `<`, and `>`:

> **THTMLEncoding** only encodes reserved HTML characters: `"&<>`.

But it also is able to decode *numeric* character references:

> **THTMLEncoding** supports decoding any HTML numeric character reference, such as `&#169;` or `&#254;`, as well as the character entity references of reserved HTML characters: `&quot;`, `&amp;`, `&lt;`, `&gt;`.

So the only named character entities it supports are the ones for the HTML reserved characters `"`, `&`, `<`, and `>`.

Indeed, the documentation emphasises and warns

> **Warning:** Decoding character entity references of non-reserved characters, such as `&apos;` or `&copy;`, is not supported. The input data must not contain any other character entity references. Otherwise, the output data may be corrupted.

Fortunately, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1657105/282848) (and the answer by Ian Boyd) contains code to decode HTML character entities other than those for the reserved characters.